# how to append 2 varible using pipe delimeter

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

Input:

```
var1="abc"
var2="|"
var3= "def"
var4=$var1$var2$var3
echo $v4
```

I have tired above thing but could not able to achieve

Getting output:

```
abc def
```

Expected output:

```
abc | def
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I checked. It works with minor fixes:

Removed extra space after = at line 3, add spaces inside in line 2, fix variable name v4 to var4 at line 5.

```
var1="abc"
var2=" | "
var3="def"
var4=$var1$var2$var3
echo $var4
```